# How to connect an Android app to live remote datadase like 000webhost?

Tags: php, android, mysql, server, xampp

I just learned how to connect an Android app to a database using Xampp server. Now I want to use a live, free remote server like 000webhost but I can't figure out where is the problem.

My 000webhost domain info:

> Domain    benbenben.net23.net
>   Username    a5323947
>   Password    Change Disk
>   Usage 0.02
>   Bandwidth   100000 MB (100GB)
>   Home Root   /home/a5323947 Server
>   Name  server20.000webhost.com
>   IP Address  31.170.160.84 Apache
>   ver.  2.2.19 (Unix)
>   PHP version 5.2.*
>   MySQL ver.  5.1
>   Activated On    2016-05-02 13:25
>   Status  Active

Database info:

> MySQL Database a5323947_my
>   MySQL User a5323947_my
>   MySQL Host mysql4.000webhost.com

And this is the PHP code I use to connect to the database:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    define('DB_USER', "a5323947_my");
    define('DB_PASSWORD', "****");
    define('DB_DATABASE', "a5323947_my");
    define('DB_SERVER', "mysql4.000webhost.com");
?>
```

HTTP request link:

```
http://benbenben.net23.net.com/myapp/example.php
```

The code works well using Xampp server but it doesn't when using live server...
Please, help me changing PHP code and/or the request...
Thanks!

Comment: is the app directly connecting to the database or just a web page?

Comment: not directly !!! the app  connect firstly with the php file

Comment: now explain exactly what is "not working"

Comment: Sorry for my bad english......I am working on app have activity to regist contain name ,mbile ,email.....when i use xampp server it work perfectly...

Comment: Improved text formatting and code indentation, fixed some grammar and title